# Is there an alternative way to change Username In ORACLE DB?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-schema

I want to make test on a database which is already using by others.

So I came up with the idea that I create a new DB and creates all the tables functions packages from old DB. I made the tests, it's OK to use new DB but I want to switch two DB.

I thought that I could simply change the username after deleting old DB but apparently I cant do that.

Is there an alternative way to change Username In ORACLE DB?

Comment: Do you mean a new schema, or actually a new database? The Oracle meaning of database is different to other RDBMSs, so you need to be clear what you actually want. You can't change the name of a schema though. Does your application rely on a fixed DB or schema name, or can that be modified to refer to the new one?

Comment: You could drop the old schema, recreate it (or just drop all of its objects) and copy the new one back to the old, e.g. with datapump. You'd have to be pretty sure you had everything you needed first, and/or not care about data loss, and hopefully not be doing this on a production system without extensive testing *8-)

Comment: The **ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=** command may be useful in this situation.  You could execute this command via your application, or setup a logon trigger to execute it, so when you log into that user id it will default to the new schema.

Comment: I meant new schema,
i cant edit the schema names in the applications. That's why i intended to change schema's name

Comment: The solution I proposed won't work if you explicitly call out your schema names in your application (i.e. select * from **old_schema**.table_name).  If that's the case then Alex's solution of recreating the old schema and copying the new schema's objects into it seems like your best option.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant use the ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA in application they may use old_sche.table_name as mtwaddell said. Alex's option seems to be best for my problem for now. But of course i can use another option if someone have an answer for this   :)

Comment: @SercanSülün After giving it a little more thought, you might be able to drop all the objects in the old schema and then create synonyms in that schema that point to the objects in new schema.